# PHP - Session and database issue

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database, session

When i print my session, this is the result i get, the index is the id from the product that has been added, and the quantity on the right of the index.
Now the problem is: I want to show the names of the products that are saved in the database by the id you see in my arrays indexes..
How can I print all the product names?

```
    Meal1:
Array
    (
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 4
        [7] => 12
        [9] => 6
    )

    Meal2:

    Array
    (
        [2] => 1
        [7] => 5
        [9] => 2
    )

    Meal3:

    Array
    (
        [2] => 2
        [7] => 4
        [9] => 4
    )
```

Comment: SHOW QUESRY THAT YOU HAVE USED

Comment: Maybe you could share your code with us along with a screenshot of your database? (Or just the row names)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should loop on your database with the id in your array when displaying name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$MealKeys=array_keys($data);
$cntKeys=count($MealKeys);
for ($i=0;$i<$cntKeys;$i++)
{
    //print $MealKeys[$i];
    $productKeys=array_keys($data[$MealKeys[$i]]);
    for ($product_counter=0;$product_counter<count($productKeys);$product_counter++)
    print $productKeys[$product_counter];           
}
```

I suppose from your print that you have array of array. You need to iterate on "Meal" Keys and in this way you obtain (Meal1, Meal2 ...). For each key (you obtain Keys using array_keys($array), you iterate to get Keys of products.

Please specify your variables or some code in order to explain better your problem, if this is not the right answer.

Bye